# Mocking Input events in karma jasmine

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following piece of code,

```
 private _whenMouseEntered(ev: MouseEvent) {
        //Do something when the mouse enters the HTMLELEMENT.
}
```

The above code is attached to an htmlelement.

How to mock this method in karma jasmine.This is a pure typescript project without any frameworks
I can only use karma, jasmine and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a private method, I assume that you have something like this somewhere in your code:

```
assignEvent() { 
  this.htmlElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", this._whenMouseEntered) 
}
```

If so, you have to mock the `htmlElement` first, to be able to fake call the registered callback:

```
describe("executing callback", () => {
  let callbackRef: (e: any) => void;
  let event: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    event = {
      preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy()
    };
    htmlElementMock.addEventListener = (name: string, callback: (e: any) => void) => {
      callbackRef = callback;
    };
    controller.htmlElement = htmlElement;
  });

  it("checks that preventDefault was called", () => {
    controller.assignEvent();

    callbackRef!(event);

    event.preventDefault.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```